# Unable to create routes based on a list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-state

Why Am I unable to map through a list and create routes with this code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  const array1 = [];
  const array2 = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    array1.push({ name: "dev", bio: "yeah" });
    array1.push({ name: "kirath", bio: 'yeah it"s big brain time' });
    console.log(array1);
    array1.map((object) => {
      array2.push(object.name);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {array2.map((name) => {
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i have tried to look at a lot of different ways but unable to do so...My actual motive is to connect this to firebase realtime database but i just hard coded the data for now because i was unable to create routes with this type of data why?

Answer (score 1):

Your `array2` is constant and not `state`, that is why at first render it is an empty array.

You push items to `array2` but your component does not rerender.

You need to do it like this.

```
const [array2, setArray2] = useState([])
```

and in `useEffect` you need to

```
const newPushedArray = array1.map(name) => <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />
```

`setArray2(newPushedArray)`

Comment: thx for answer but then i am getting this error :  array2.map is not a function

Comment: You need to set set useState default value an empty array.

like useState([])

Comment: sorry if i am being very silly bro but still did not understand that what should i write?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  const array1 = [];
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    array1.push({ name: "dev", bio: "yeah" });
    array1.push({ name: "kirath", bio: 'yeah it"s big brain time' });
    console.log(array1);
   const newArray = array1.map((object) => object.name);
setArray2(newArray);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {array2.map((name) => {
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just replace Routes with Switch and try it.

import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// code 
<Switch>
 `{array2.map((name) => {
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>}/> })}`
</Switch>
```

Comment: It appears OP is using `react-router-dom@6` which doesn't export a `Switch` component. This code won't work and will throw invariant errors. The `Routes` component is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The main issue is that there is no React state and the variables you are mutating are being updated *after* the component has rendered since the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle. In other words, the component renders with `array1` and `array2` being empty, ***then*** the `useEffect` hook callback is called and the arrays are mutated. Since there is no state involved there is nothing to trigger a rerender. This wouldn't matter though because even if you did manage to trigger another render cycle the `array1` and `array2` arrays would be redeclared again as empty arrays and the issue would remain the same.

```
function App() {
  const array1 = []; // <-- declared empty each render cycle
  const array2 = []; // <-- declared empty each render cycle

  useEffect(() => {
    array1.push({ name: "dev", bio: "yeah" });
    array1.push({ name: "kirath", bio: 'yeah it"s big brain time' });
    console.log(array1);
    array1.map((object) => {
      array2.push(object.name);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {array2.map((name) => { // <-- always empty when rendered
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

The arrays should be declared declared in state if you want to update them via the `useEffect`. Instead of two arrays, just use a single array and when mapping to JSX access the `name` property.

```
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.setState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPeople([
      { name: "dev", bio: "yeah" },
      { name: "kirath", bio: 'yeah it"s big brain time' },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {people.map(({ name }) => {
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course, if you already know what the array contents will be it would be better to just initialize the array value so the values are available on the initial render.

```
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.setState([
    { name: "dev", bio: "yeah" },
    { name: "kirath", bio: 'yeah it"s big brain time' },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {people.map(({ name }) => {
          return <Route path={`/${name}`} element={<h1>hello {name}</h1>} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another improvement I'd suggest is to only render a single route with a dynamic path parameter.

Example:

```
const Person = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  return <h1>hello {name}</h1>;
};

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.setState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ... business logic to fetch people from firebase ...
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {people.map(({ name }) => (
          <li>
            <Link to={`/${name}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:name" element={<Person />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering (pls do not be offended) i did not understand a thing

Comment: @DevContractor No worries. Depending on where you are coming from React can have a pretty steep learning curve. Basically the gist is that array used to store the "people" objects needs to be part of a React state so that when it's updated it triggers the component to rerender with the new state value. React UI is a function of state and props. If you are not updating state or props then nothing will be updated from React's point of view and nothing gets rerendered. I offered three solutions, none of them made any sense at all? Or is there something you need help understanding?